# Windows API - registering a hotkey with multiple keys combination

Tags: c++, winapi, hotkeys

So for example I can easily register a hotkey that is a combination of Shift, Alt (Mod keys) and Up arrow:

`RegisterHotKey(NULL, TOP, MOD_SHIFT | MOD_ALT, VK_UP);`

This works just fine but what I'm after is registering a hotkey with the same keys as above PLUS another normal key like Left arrow, so the combination would be Shift, Alt, Up arrow, Left arrow.

There isn't space in the function for another argument, and I tried doing a bitwise OR for the Up and Left arrow keys like

`VK_UP | VK_LEFT`

... but it's not working. If anyone encountered this problem before or knows how I proceed please help!

Comment: You can't do that using the hotkey API. You could try checking (using `GetKeyState`) if the second key is held down when your primary hotkey is triggered, but I suspect it may not be triggered at all if the user presses the two keys in the "wrong" order.

Comment: My program uses Shift + Alt + Up as one of its shortcuts. Your program just broke my program. Or in other words, global hotkeys are only appropriate in a kiosk situation, the very situation where you don't need them!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I believe RegisterHotkey(...) doesn't work when trying to register a hotkey that's already in use.

Comment: My app does not register a hot key. It's a simple short cut. But your program just took over that key press rendering my app broken. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Anyone who would use the program would be aware of what the hotkeys are and change the keys if needed. I can't predict what thousands of combinations there already are in use by different programs. Also could you elaborate what you mean by a kiosk situation?

Comment: You might think so, but I deal with support queries from my clients who are upset that when they use my program shortcuts the computer does very weird things because of other software that assumes it is the only software running. In my experience it is Intel laptop display drivers, and it drives my customers potty. It's me they come to. Almost always it is wrong for a desktop application to register a global hotkey. At the very least, if you feel you must register a global hotkey, don't do it by default. Make your users do it explicitly, with suitable warnings.

Comment: RegisterHotkey() defines a global, system-wide hotkey. Not just one for your program. So when @DavidHeffernan uses his shortcut in his program it won't work anymore whenever your program is running. That might be hard to notice for the user, as he thinks the actual program is broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows hotkeys don't support multiple (non-modifiers) keys. You cannot bitwise OR multiple `VK_*` values, only `MOD_*` values can be combined.

If you desperately need this feature then you have to use a [low-level keyboard hook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644985(v=vs.85).aspx) and track the keys yourself. Hooking affects global system performance and should be avoided if possible.

If you decide to do this you have to remember that Windows users are not used to pressing hotkeys this way, only menus allow a somewhat similar pattern but you don't have to hold the <kbd>Alt</kbd> modifier to make those work. You must also remember to test your hook with [StickyKeys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_keys) and other accessibility features...